# Return Alphanumerics -issue with combining pieces of the function

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return, alphanumeric

Submitted earlier about this, at this point all the pieces work separately, but not together. I've tried moving things around to see if it was simply an order issue, but that didn't fixe it. Trying to put them in one big if/else also didn't seem to work. I can either get the string to display only alphanumerics characters OR display 'not a string', but I cannot get the code to work to do both. 
**This section will return the proper alphanumerics only:**

```
function nothingSpecial(str) {
  var re = /[A-Z\s0-9]/i;
  var newStr = '';

  for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
    if (re.test(str[i])){
      newStr = newStr + str[i];
    }
  }
   return newStr;
   if(str.length <= 0) {
    return ("Not a string!");
  }

      if (typeof str !== String) {
        return "Not a string!"} 

    }

nothingSpecial("asdfalsd@#$#")
```

**This will return "not a string!", even if it should show alphanumerics, but is correct or seemingly so for numbers and ""**

```
function nothingSpecial(str) {

  var re = /[A-Z\s0-9]/i;
  var newStr = '';

    if(str.length <= 0) {
    return ("Not a string!");
  }

  if (typeof str !== String) {
    return "Not a string!"} 

  for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
    if (re.test(str[i])){
      newStr = newStr + str[i];
    }
  }
   return newStr;

    }
nothingSpecial(23)
```

What am I doing wrong?   -Thank you in advance!

Comment: The first snippet has a return in the middle of the function, the other lines will not be executed

Comment: What are you trying to do? Even if you submittited earlier, how can we know it?

Comment: Your second snippet correctly returns "not a string" as you are calling the function with a number argument (23). A number is not a string.

Comment: @edc65 -is there ever a way around this? It seems like you can have mutliple return options as long as they are within blocks (for example, multiple separate if/else statements) 

It's just practice. I know the easy way is with .replace, I am practicing using loops are wanted to see how to make it work. 

I posted earlier (separate post) about a different issue with the code. 

Thank you for checking out the code!

Comment: Your return is fine where it is, but you're checking that 'str' is a function, not that it's a string. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Okay, based on your comment, here you go:

This is your problem:

```
if (typeof str !== String)
```

You're comparing the result of `typeof str`, which is a string, with the [object constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) for strings, `String`, which is a function. It's failing because you're not actually checking for a string, you're comparing a string (the output of `typeof`, which is always a string regardless of the type you're checking) with a function. Your comparison should instead look like this:

```
if (typeof str !== 'string')
```

Edit: Heres a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ggu1t4b0/1/).

Comment: My aplogies! It needs to return "not a string" when numbers (or anything not a string is passed in) -it shouldn't covert numbers to a string.

Comment: I addressed two errors you made, the fix for the second one would have solved that for you. I've edited my answer to remove the reference to the first one.

Answer (score 0):

To take any kind of argument, converting to string and keep just alphanumeric characters:

```
function nothingSpecial(str) {

  str += '' // convert any argument to string

  str = str.replace(/[^A-Z\s0-9]/gi, "") // remove all characters except alphanumeric and any kind of space (newlines too)

  return str
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had posted previously about the same code chunk and this was recommended. I was hoping to try using loops for practice otherwise yeah this is totally the way to go!